# Function name must be a string Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-6

I want to displaying the date in my local language but when i try to do that i have this error

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Function name must be a string

```
<?php
use Carbon\Carbon;
?>

<h4>Time Item Added:
       <h5>{{ Carbon::setLocale('id')
            (\Carbon\Carbon::parse($transactionsin->item_added_date)->format('D, d-m-Y'))}}</h5>
</h4>
```

also with `format('D, d-m-y')` with display the date to `Mon, 01-12-2019`

How to change `format` so the day name is in full name `Monday, 01-12-2019`

Comment: `format('l, d-m-y')` I checked in the manual, you could have done that

Comment: Why are you using `Carbon` and `\Carbon\Carbon`? You should probably separate those two `Carbon` calls `{{Carbon::setLocale('id')}} ({{\Carbon\Carbon::parse(...)}})` Also, not sure if `id` is a valid locale, that would be `id-ID`

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem? It should be fairly simple to remove the parts that work until you have a minimal example that triggers the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h4>
    Time Item Added:
       <h5><?php Carbon::setLocale('id'); ?>
            {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($transactionsin->item_added_date)->format('D, d-m-Y') }}</h5>
</h4>
```

{{ }} does try to echo something into the view. So you shouldn't try to execute just a regular PHP statement that way.